# Different ways to define which database to use?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I am trying to find out the differences in the way you can define which database to use in SSMS.

Is there any functional difference between using the 'Available Databases' drop down list

[Adventure works Available Databases dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmfdM.png),

the database being defined in the query

```
SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2008.dbo.Customers
```

and
stating the database at the start?

```
USE AdventureWorks2008
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers
```

I'm interested to know if there is a difference in terms of performance or something that happens behind the scenes for each case.

Thank you for your help

Comment: never saw any difference in performance in all three methods you had mention

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Very very small overhead is added when you use "USE AdventureWorks2008" as it will execute it against the database every time you execute the query. It also will print the "Command(s) completed successfully.". However it is so small overhead and if you are OK with this message then just do not care about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can be the difference.

When you execute statements like this: `SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2008.dbo.Customers` in the context of *another* database (not AdventureWorks2008) that another database's settings are applied.

First of all, any database has its [Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level) that can be different, so it can limit usage of some code, for example you cannot use `APPLY` operator in the context of database with CL set to 80 but you can do it within database with CL >= 90

Second, every database has its own set of options such as `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC` and `Forced Parameterization` that can affect your query plan.
I did encounter some cases when the context of database influenced the plan:

One case was when I created filtered index for one table and it was used in the plan until I executed my query in the context of database with Simple parameterization, and it was not used for the same query when executed in the context of database with Forced parameterization. When I used the hint to force that index I've got the error that the query plan cannot be produced due to query hint, so I need to investigate and I found out that my query was parameterized and instead of my condition `fld = 0` there was `fld = @p` and it could not use my filtered index with `fld = 0` condition.

The second case was reguarding table cardinality estimation: we use staging tables to load the data in our ETL procedures and then switch then to actual tables like this:

```
insert into stg with(tablock);
 ...
truncate table actual;
alter table stg swith to actual;
```

All the staging tables are empty when the procedure compiles but within the proc they are filled with the data, so when we do joins between them they are not emty anymore. Passing from 0 rows to non-0 rows triggers statement recompilation that should take in consideration actual number of rows, but it did not happen on the production server, so all estimations were completely wrong (1 row fo every table) and I need to investigate. The cause was `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC` set to ON in production database.
Now imagine you have 2 db: db1 and db2 with this option set to ON and OFF respectively, in db1 this code will have wrong estimations while if you execute it in db2 using db1.dbo.stg it will have right estimations. The execution time will be very different in these 2 databases.